# problems with impagination of the page

Tags: css

i have this code:

```
#forumpost
{
    min-height:150px;
}
.forumpost-display
{
    display: inline-block;
    width:160px;
    min-height: 150px;
}
.forumpost-content
{
    display: inline-block;
    width:700px;
]
```

here the link: http://www.freeflying.it/test/?p=forum&topic=show&t=1

why is the post content on the bottom? how can i solve it? i'm getting crazy.
i can't use position relative and float because it make problems.
i can't also use display:block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this adding `vertical-align: top;` to `.forumpost-content` line 263 of your `style.css`

Comment: OMG thank you so muchhhhh!!!!!!! LOVE YOU GUY!! i'm falling in love with this website and it's users :)

Comment: you are welcome. please set the question as answered if it suits you :)